# Add a loop to split master information into separate sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master list of Companies and directors salaries per year. It is a long list of about 200 lines. Many of the directors work for more than one company.

I want to split each directors information and paste it into a worksheet. One new worksheet for each director.

Master excel file

```
Name       Company       Salary
Adam       A Company     $20,000
Boris      B Company     $5,000
Adam       S Company     $2,000
Carl       C Company     $81,000
...
```

New excel file - worksheet 1

```
Name       Company       Salary
Adam       A Company     $20,000
Adam       S Company     $2,000
```

New excel file - worksheet 2

```
Boris      B Company     $5,000
```

Here is the VBA code I wrote. It only works for one director at a time, how do I loop it so it will run for each director?

```
Sub sort()

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow

  If Cells(i, 1) = "Adam" Then

    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\summary.xlsm"
    Dim p As Integer, q As Integer
    p = Worksheets.Count

    For q = 1 To p
      If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(q).Name = "Adam" Then
        Worksheets("Adam").Select
      End If
    Next q

    erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

 End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: first find all distinct names in the list and save it/store this in memory (create an array). Then create a loop outside the currently existing loop, this new loop with go through the list with distinct names.

Comment: Alternatively you could just loop through and per record decide to which sheet (an existing or a new one) it should go. If you name your worksheets in the new excel the same as the directors' names you can easily check if the a sheet already exists.

Comment: Last alterative would be to sort the list in the master excel by Name. Then copy parts of this sorted list in blocks with equal Name values to a new worksheet in your new excel and move to the next line (I think I like this last one best)